# When use body-parser module in my app , get GET ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: angularjs, node.js, body-parser

I have this Error when I'm trying to load my website

> GET http://localhost:3000/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I'm using Mean Stack Technologies,
When I remove `app.use(bodyParser.json);` from my code the page load very well

the code of my server.js file :

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
var authenticationController = require('./server/controllers/authentication-controller');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/time-waste');
app.use(bodyParser.json);
app.use('/app',express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
app.use('/node_modules',express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('./index.html');
});

//Authentication
app.post('/api/user/signup',authenticationController.signup);
app.listen('3000',function(){
    console.log("listening on port 3000");

});
```

the auth controller file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('../datasets/users');


module.exports.signup = function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    var user = new User(req.body);
    user.save();
    res.json(req.body);
};
```

the angular controller

```
angular.module('TimeWaste').controller('signUpController',['$scope','$state','$http',function($scope,$state,$http){
    $scope.createUser = function(){
        console.log($scope.newUser);
        $http.post('api/user/signup',$scope.newUser).success(function(response){

        }).error(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Can you log the `req.body`, don't you have a parameter 'user' in your res.body ? Because your `new User(res.body)` looks weird to me

Comment: If I remove the use bodyParser statement the req.body is undefined but the page work fine when I just add this statement the page load for very long time then this error occured and no I don't have param called user in res.body !